# Focus the field after selecting the jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

How to set focus in the datepicker field right after selecting date from picker?

```html
<input type="text" class="datepicker">
```

```js
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

Comment: This question has taken a particular jQuery UI bent.  Here's a separate question on [re-focusing the field for the **Bootstrap Datepicker**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28172785/1366033)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [onClose](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onClose) or [onSelect](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) handler based on your need

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    onClose: function(){
        this.focus()
    }
});
```

Demo: [On Close](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/A8e55/), [On Select](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3zs5K/)

Comment: This does not work in IE11, the calendar will not close.

Comment: @user1929393 check this out http://www.objectpartners.com/2012/06/18/jquery-ui-datepicker-ie-focus-fix/